# Existing Pages as Apps

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I have several existing Pages that when I login to https://developers.facebook.com/apps

All show up in my Apps list. However the one page (not created my be but I am an admin) does not.

How do I access this Page as an App (with out creating an new App that will create a second page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook apps also have their own facebook pages on facebook itsself.

eg: https://www.facebook.com/nameofapp

This might be your way to get to the app page.

Comment: I understand that, but some of my pages are also listed as apps. I have never set them up as apps, they will never be apps. And I'd like to avoid having 2 pages for the same service.